# How to wrap multiple JPA EntityManager persist/merge into single transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I need to update several tables in a single transaction.

Currently, I have the following structure in my code:

(pseudo-code)

```
process(updateList, mainObject);  // returns list of objects and main business object to persist/update
persistTable1(mainObject);  // table 1

int objectIndex = 0;
while(objectIndex < updateList.size()) {
    persistTable2(updateList[objectIndex]); // table 2
    objectIndex++;
}
```

Question:
How do I wrap the persistTable1 (which will always get called once - no matter what), and the persistTable2 call (which will get called 0 to n times) into a single transaction, so that if any persist/merge fails then everything will get rolled-back?

The persist/update code is using JPA EntityManager.

Comment: Are you using Container-managed transactions?  This might help [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncij.html)

Comment: Basically just put the code in a method with an active transaction.

Comment: @Thevenin - Yes, container managed (TomEE).  I should also mention that this is happening in a RESTful Web Service call (Jersey).  Does that matter?

Comment: I'm not certain but I don't think that matters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the transactional context in the method caller.

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

Comment: This won't work for my project since it is container managed and not using Spring.